# Inno Setup: Is it possible to set own group identifier for Dirs permission?

Tags: permissions, inno-setup

I want to create folder for specific usergroup with ID 23 on program installation. 
But inno setup allows to specify only [built in groups](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=usergroupids) in Permission attibute for [Dirs] section.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl And is it possible to check if command exists py Inno Setup?

Comment: What command? Do you mean the `icalcs`?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl,  yes

Comment: The `icalcs` is supported on all currently supported versions of Windows (Vista and newer). If you need to support Windows XP too, use `cacls` (The `cacls` is deprecated in the later versions of Windows, but still works in Windows 10).

Comment: In the end, I've decided to use custom dll for this purpose.